# Filter In Method

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I use the Filter.In method?

I have a document like this:

```
{ 
  "File" : "xxxxxxx.txt",
  "Content" : [
      {   "tag" : "Book",
          "name" : "TestBook1",
          "value" : "xxx"
      },
      {   "tag" : "Dept",
          "name" : "TestDept1",
          "value" : "yyy"
      },
      {   "tag" : "Employee", 
          "name" : "TestEmployee1",
          "value" : "zzz"
      }]
}
```

I know with a filter like this:

```
var subFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("tag", "Dept");
```

I can get

```
{   
    "tag" : "Dept",
    "name" : "TestDept1",
    "value" : "yyy"
}
```

Supposed I have a lot of different tags and I want to find any ones that are in a string like "Book, Dept, Employee, xxxxx, yyyyy, zzzzz....."

I try to use the `Filter.In()` method but can't quite figure out how to pass in the required parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create an `IEnumerable` (something with a `Contains` method).

So, if your tags were separated by commas, you could:

```
var tags = tagsString.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(p => p.Trim());
var results = await collection.Find(p => tags.Contains(p.Tag)).ToListAsync();
```

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/expressions/

Comment: Josh K, thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for.